# Unity: When attaching my custom camera script camera shakes when player starts to move fast

Tags: unity, c#, camera, movement

Here is my player code.

```
Rigidbody rb;

Vector3 currMovement;
public float jumpSpeed = 10;
public float moveSpeed = 10;
public float rotSpeed = 180;

float distToGround;

public float posSmoothTime = 0.5f;
float currPos;
float targetPos;
float posVel;

public float rotSmoothTime = 0.5f;
float currRot;
float targetRot;
float rotVel;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    distToGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
}

bool isGrounded() { return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround + 0.1f); }

void Update()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    // Rotation smoothing.
    targetRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;

    if (targetRot > 360)
        targetRot -= 360;
    if (targetRot < 0)
        targetRot += 360;
    currRot = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currRot, targetRot, ref rotVel, rotSmoothTime * Time.smoothDeltaTime);

    transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, currRot, 0);

    // Movement smoothing.
    targetPos = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

    currPos = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currPos, targetPos, ref posVel, posSmoothTime * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
    currMovement = new Vector3(0, 0, currPos);
    currMovement = transform.rotation * currMovement;

    if (isGrounded())
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * jumpSpeed;
    }

    rb.position += currMovement * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
}
```

I have a Rigidbody attached to my player. I think the problem is with my camera script. Here is my camera script.

```
public Transform player;
Quaternion targetLook;
Vector3 targetMove;
public float smoothLook = 0.5f;
public float smoothMove = 0.5f;
public float distFromPlayer = 5, heightFromPlayer = 3;
Vector3 moveVel;

void LateUpdate()
{
    CameraMove();
}

void CameraMove()
{
    targetMove = player.position + (player.rotation * new Vector3(0, heightFromPlayer, -distFromPlayer));
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetMove, ref moveVel, smoothMove);

    targetLook = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetLook, smoothLook);
}
```

}

The player is not an parent of my camera. When I parent the player to my camera the shake stops. But I want a custom smooth camera movement with my custom scirpt, so I can't make the player a parent of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it :D. I just multiplied Time.deltaTime to smoothLook.